# Нужно вычислить сумму с помощью циклa for

Tags: c++, ряды

задано натуральное число `n`, нужно вычислить сумму `S = (-1)^n * (n+1)/(2n+1)` с помощью циклa for
[image: вот код, но здесь есть ошибка, ибо программа неправильно считает]

Comment: Чудесно! Вам прямо код написать?

Comment: желательно, есть уже код, но он с ошибкой, ибо правильное значение выдает только при n = 0, так хотя бы найду ошибку

Comment: "есть уже код" - секретный?

Comment: А что вы уже сделали? Что не получилось? Сообщество поможет с решением проблемы, а не за полное написание кода с нуля имея только условие

Comment: @assneils покажите код для того что бы мы указали на пробел или ошибку

Comment: вот, добавил скрин, как-то так

Comment: текстовую информацию необходимо прилагать в виде текста.

Comment: @assneils Никто не будет ваш код перепечатывать, чтобы попробовать запустить. Поэтому тут принято, как написали выше, код давать в виде текста.

Comment: приложите код в теле вопроса в виде текста

Comment: Минус вопросу за плохое оформление: код надо прикладывать текстом.

Answer (score 4):

у вас `n` это целое число, а значит  (`n+1`) и (`2n+1`) тоже целые числа. При делении вы получите в результате целое число (так как компилятор не может знать что вам нужно), т.е. результат будет ноль. Ваш желаемый результат должен иметь тип `double`, и нужно так и написать:  ...`double (n+1)/(2n+1)`...

Вообшем это может выглядеть так:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
double s = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) 
    s += pow(-1, i) * (double)(i + 1) / (2 * i + 1);        

cout << s;
```

Comment: ооооо, я нашёл ошибку, спасибо большое :)

Answer (score 0):

Вы почему-то цикл делаете по `i`, а суммируете один и тот же член с `n`, да еще добавленной единицей. И еще зачем-то лишний плюс один дописали...

```
unsigned int n;
double s = 0.0;
cin >> n;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
    s += ((i % 2 == 0) ? 1 : -1) * (i + 1.0) / (2.0 * i + 1.0);
    }

cout << s << endl;
```